# How do I map Grails Domain Classes to DTOs?

Tags: java, grails, groovy, dto, grails-domain-class

I have a Grails project with domain classes. This persistent classes should be mapped to Java DTOs. I found a very old Grails plugin [here](http://grails.org/plugin/dto) which does not really solves the problem.

Is there a plugin or a way to:

- annotate domain class properties which are mapped to the corresponding DTO class?
- set a custom mapping function for class properties?
- an easy way to convert a DTO into a domain class and vice versa?

Comment: Maybe the best way to do that is to rewrite the old plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how would you like to manage persistence but for object mapping you can use Java libraries like [Dozer](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/) or [Orika](https://code.google.com/p/orika/).